# Multiple assets download in Newsstand

Tags: ios, download

In my app I have to download many assets instead of a single zip.How can I recode the program to be a Newsstand one?　THX

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to tell you how to recode what you have if we can't see any code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple assets to a newsstand issue and they can all be downloaded sequentially if you call `downloadWithDelegate:` on them. It is better to do a single zip if you can though as it's much easier to manage and resuming the download is a bit simpler and less prone to getting confused in the code with multiple downloads going on.